# Passing Parameters from calendar disp form to newform custom list

Tags: forms-7

LISTS INVOLVED
- Calendar
- EVENTS

PROCESS
When the calendar event is clicked it opens the display form displaying the event information and the newform.aspx from a different custom list called"Events". The "Meeting Title" field(Calendar List) is a lookup field which gets the event title from (Calendar List). This is done through Infopath.

WHATS NEEDED
When the calendar event is clicked, the event name(CAlendar List) should be auto-populated in "Meeting Title" Field.
Need a simple solution in infopath or SPD, am not technically strong. Thanks in advance for your help.
[image: REference]

Comment: https://flic.kr/p/rMjmPc

Answer (score 0):

That is not doable with a layer using InfoPath. While you may be able to do something in SharePoint Designer using JavaScript, if you're not strong in technology, I'd say this is out of reach.

If you're feeling ambitious, you can achieve this with one of the variety of JavaScript calendars that query a list and get back a JSON object. Clicking on a link in the calendar would then launch a layer to display a custom InfoPath form.

Comment: Can you give step by step instruction?

Comment: Not really since it involves tying together multiple things. There's no out of the box/single tutorial/easy answer for what you want to do. This is one of those self-research via Google things (ie 'SharePoint JSON REST'). A jQuery calendar that is pretty easy to work with is [Full Calendar](http://fullcalendar.io/).